# how can I improve this python script?

Tags: python

[Backup Script](http://dpaste.com/hold/290121/)

Please check the link above, I wrote this small script in python. It backup files from one directory to the other depends upon the user input. I want to know what are the limitations of this script and all the improvements that can be done to it. So that I can learn from my mistakes, I am total beginner to programming and python. Thanks

Comment: You are a total beginner and you wrote that code? Kudos. You can start improving it by naming some variables in a more readable manner. (can somebody help me improve the previous sentence?)

Comment: Actually I started using python last week. I started with A Byte of python tutotial By Swaroop CH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use raw_input, use command-line parameters.
To do this use the [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) module (or [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) for Python 2.7+). Also the use of `os.system` is not recommented, see [Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) for a replacement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will rewrite the script using this module

Comment: This is a very nice suggestion, you code would probably be just a few line if you use it correctly. Functions are being very long (if not too long) here because of all the parsing.

Comment: Yes, the functions are unnecessarily long. I will definitely use these suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can replace all os.system (either mk_d, or tar) by pythonic commands  `os.mkdir()` ([mkdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkdir)) and [tarfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will rewrite the script using these moduls.